# Using awk inside ssh from ruby

Tags: ruby, bash, command-line, ssh

When running the command:

```
puts `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i keyfile user@host "sudo cat file | awk '/^server/ {print \$2}' | sort -u"`
```

After running this command, its only counts the `^server`, but it ignores the `print $2` command.
i get the whole line instead of just the 2nd word.

Comment: Did you also try your `ssh` command at the bash prompt to make sure it does what you expect?

Comment: the command works locally with ruby, but when i try to use it with ssh from another host, it doesnt work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're running through a couple of shell processing layers, so you need an additional backslash:

```
puts `ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i keyfile user@host "sudo cat file | awk '/^server/ {print \\$2}' | sort -u"`
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you change this:

```
sudo cat file | awk '/^server/ {print \$2}' | sort -u
```

to this:

```
sudo cat file | grep '/^server' | awk '{ print \$2 }' | sort -u
```

If still not working, try not escaping the $ - try **$2** instead of **\$2**

Comment: its works when i try to run it from the command line, but when i run it from within ruby, it ignores the print :(

Answer (score 0):

Might be more maintainable to split it up into pieces. Also using ruby's single quoting mechanism works to send the command as you intend.

```
cmd = %q(sudo cat file | awk '/^server/ {print $2}' | sort -u)
puts  %x(ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -i keyfile user@host #{cmd})
```